# Old Session id not available

Tags: python-3.x, session, flask

`app.py` file having flask application. `test_app.py` file having code related request module to invoke flask app url with id values.

Both `app.py` and `test_app.py` i am ruing in two different command prompt.

when request is sending 2nd time with `id="10122"` from the `test_app.py` the old session `id` is None. Why it is `None`? already my first request set a `id` in the session and second time i am accessing the old(first) request `id`.

for my second request with `id = "10122"` old session id should be `10121`.

```
      1.current output: 
         Old session id: None 
         New session id: 10121

      2.Expected Output:
          Old session id: 10121
          New session id: 10122

(base) H:\Python\DevPractice\day4>python app.py
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
********started********
Old session id: None
New session id: 10121
************end**********
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2019 14:28:27] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
********started********
Old session id: None
New session id: 10122
************end**********
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2019 14:28:27] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

invoking from the test_app.py

```
(base) H:\Python\DevPractice\day4>python test_app.py
results
results
```

1. app.py file

```
    from flask import Flask, make_response, redirect, session, url_for,    request

    SECRET_KEY = 'develop'

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(__name__)

    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
    def index():
        print("********started********")

        old_id = session.get('id', None)
        print("Old session id:", old_id )
        if request.method == 'POST':
            session['id'] = request.form['id']
        #session['hello'] = 'world!'
        new_id = session.get('id', None)
        print("New session id:", new_id )
        print("************end**********")
        return "results"

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

2. test_app.py file

```
    import requests
    list_id = ["10121", "10122"]
    for i in list_id:
        payload = {'id': i}
        r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", data=payload)
        print(r.text)
```

Comment: @ngShravil.py thanks... do you have any idea about above problem ?

Comment: Even I am also facing similar problem, you can check this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206878/flask-session-is-not-staying-the-same-within-two-api-calls .